Expected value of deck of cards going back to original order in top-to-random shuffling
I have a problem in stochastic processes I would like help with:
Given a 52-card deck we shuffle the cards using Top-to-random shuffling: in each turn we take only the top card and put it somewhere in the deck.
What is the expected value of the number of shuffles until we return to the original state of the deck?
So this problem can be equated to a random walk on a regular graph: a vertex is a permutation of the numbers 1,...,52 and every vertex has exactly 52 neighbors. So I assume the expectancy of going back to the original value would be some power on (1/52).
I also assume the uniform distribution is stationary for this Markov chain but I'm not sure how to go about computing the expected value.

Related, probably very helpful: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/Papers/shuffling.pdf

I got my answer so writing here in favor of anyone viewing this question:
We will be using Kac's lemma:
Kac's lemma
This problem can be equated to a random walk on a graph G=(V,E) with V being the permutations of 52. Every vertex has a degree of 52 and since the shuffling is random then we walk on any edge with a probability of 1/52.
Since this is an irreducible Markov chain it has a stationary distribution π. We get that π=1/52! works. (uniform distribution). So from the lemma above we get that the expected value is 52!.
